# What is the purpose of Tab.TabPanel in this reactJS code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently watch a tutorial on YouTube about making Tabs using React and I got these codes.

**App.js**

```js
import './App.css'; 
import { Tab } from './components/Tab/Tab'; 

const tabContent = [ 
  { 
  title: "Chennai", 
  content: "Chennai is the capital of the Indian state." }, 
  { 
  title: "Lorem Ipsum", 
  content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem." 
  }, 
  { 
  title: "Dolor sit amet", 
  content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, veniam!" 
  }]; 
  
function App() { 
return (
  <>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col">
        <div className="row text-left">
          <Tab active={1}>
            { tabContent.map((tab, idx) =>
            <Tab.TabPanel key={`Tab-${idx}`} tab={tab.title}>
              {tab.content}
            </Tab.TabPanel>) }
          </Tab>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </> 
  ); 
} 

export default App;
```

**Tab.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './Tab.css'

export const Tab = ({children, active=0}) => {
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(active);
    const [tabsData, setTabsData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        let data = [];
        React.Children.forEach(children, element => {
            if(!React.isValidElement(element)) return; //exit the function

            const {props: {tab, children}} = element;
            data.push({tab, children})
        })

        setTabsData(data);

    }, [children])

    return (
        <div className="w-100 custom-tab">
            <ul className="nav nav-tabs">
                {
                    tabsData.map(({tab}, idx) => (
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <a 
                            className = {`nav-link ${idx === activeTab ? "active" : ""}`}
                            href = "#" 
                            onClick={() => setActiveTab(idx)}
                            >
                                {tab}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
            <div className="tab-content p-3">
                {tabsData[activeTab] && tabsData[activeTab].children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const TabPanel = ({children}) => {
    return {children}
}

Tab.TabPanel = TabPanel;
```

When I look to App.js I see there's a custom element named **Tab.TabPanel**. I think that is the children of the **Tab** element. And then I look to Tab.js and I see that there's TabPanel const that runs a function to return it's children.

I wonder, what is the purpose of Tab.TabPanel here? What will he render? And should I make codes like this in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the children, it's more of a namespace.  The library author didn't want to export both `Tab` and `TabPanel` and decided to attach `TabPanel` to the function that is exported (for whatever reason).  It's an opinionated choice that makes it harder to tree shake but just understand that `Tab.TabPanel` is just another React component.

The author could have just as easily done

```
export Tab = () => {...};
export TabPanel = () => {...};
```

and you could have consumed it as

```
import {Tab, TabPanel} from "./Tab.jsx";

const Foo = () => (
  <div>
    <TabPanel>
      <Tab/>
      <Tab/>
    </TabPanel>
  </div>
);
```

or however you wanted to use it.